# Using Nokogiri with mustache?

Tags: html, ruby, regex, nokogiri

I'm writing a script to convert template files to mustache, and I'd like to use Nokogiri. But is there a way to use it with mustache, specifically converting tags like `<tmpl_if var>` to `{{#var}}`? Essentially I'm trying to convert:

```
<tmpl_if foo>
    <tmpl_if bar>
        <p>Test</p>
    </tmpl_if>
</tmpl_if>
```

to

```
{{#foo}}
    {{#bar}}
        <p>Test</p>
    {{/bar}}
{{/foo}}
```

I can get the node I need to change, but I can't find a way to change just the start and end tags. Is there some way I can change the tags as strings using regex without affecting the inner HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

- with nokogiri, you change the tag names for each tmpl_if tags like this: `<tmpl_if bar>` => `<tmpl_if_bar bar>`. The goal of this change is to have the attribute name included inside the closing tag.
- you replace with gsub all the `<tmpl_if_...>` tags.

-

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_doc = <<EOD
<tmpl_if foo>
    <tmpl_if bar>
        <p>Test</p>
    </tmpl_if>
</tmpl_if>
EOD

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html_doc)
attrList = doc.xpath('//tmpl_if/@*')
attrList.each{|attr| attr.parent.name = attr.parent.name + "_" + attr.name}
html_doc = doc.css('body').inner_html

reps = [[/<tmpl_if_(\w+)[^>]*>/, '{{#\1}}'], [/<\/tmpl_if_(\w+)>/, '{{/\1}}']]
reps.each {|rep| html_doc.gsub!(rep[0], rep[1])}

puts html_doc
```

In this way you avoid all the nesting problems.

Comment: I think I found a better way that doesn't rely on that half-way change thing.

Comment: @CSturgess: In this case, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it by first finding every node that needed to change, then converting it to a string, using regex to do the replace (relying on \A and \Z) before replacing the node. If you reverse the list, it will operate on the inner nodes first. ​

```
@doc.css("tmpl_if").reverse.each do |node| 
    str = node.to_s;
    str.sub(/\A<tmpl_if ([^>]*)>(.*)<\/tmpl_if>\Z/m, '{{#\1}}\2{{/\1}}')
    node.replace(str)
end
```

`

A few changes can make this work for any/all tags like this. `\A` denotes the start of a string and `\Z` denotes the end (the string, not a line). Though they probably aren't needed considering the list already operates inside to outside, so there should only be one start and finish tag left on each node.